# Restricting which Community visitors can submit Chat request

Tags: community, chat

I recently implemented Chat for my company's Community site. The main requirement we have before going live is to be able to restrict which logged in visitors can submit a Chat request.

I've positioned the Chat button somewhere only logged in visitors can see it on our site. But we want to control which specific logged in visitors can use the Chat button. Blocking by IP Address or having the support reps block them manually are not viable for our requirements.

I'm searching for any mechanism that is able to look at a custom field value on the logged-in visitor's user record (that we would set ourselves separately) and then automatically block them from submitting a Chat request.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create page variations with and without the chat button and assigned to the users you want defining different audiences. Audiences can be defined by location, profiles, domains, user object (custom fields as you said is an option), etc.

More info:

[Page variations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_manage.htm&type=5)

[Audiences](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look into these resources and get back to you!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this worked as needed! Thank you again!

Comment: Mark it as the answer to your question. Glad you resolve it